# How Determine if a TRttiMethod is a function

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-xe

I need determine if a `TRttiMethod` is a function

so far, i wrote this function

```
Function IsFunction(QualifiedName,MethodName:string):Boolean;
Var
  ctx     : TRttiContext;
  lType   : TRttiType;
  lMethod : TRttiMethod;
Begin
    result:=false;
    ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
    lType:=ctx.FindType(QualifiedName);
    if Assigned(lType) then
    begin
       lMethod:=lType.GetMethod(MethodName);
         if Assigned(lMethod) then
           Result:=(lMethod.ReturnType<>nil); //in this line the exception is raised
    end;
End;
```

but this function fail with this exception 
`Insufficient RTTI available to support this operation.` when i test the Following

```
IsFunction('SysUtils.Exception','CreateFmt')
```

also fails with these classes and methods

```
SysUtils.Exception -> CreateFmt
SysUtils.Exception -> CreateResFmt
SysUtils.Exception -> CreateResFmt
SysUtils.Exception -> CreateFmtHelp
SysUtils.Exception -> CreateResFmtHelp
SysUtils.Exception -> CreateResFmtHelp
SysUtils.TEncoding -> Convert
SysUtils.TEncoding -> Convert
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetBufferEncoding
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetBufferEncoding
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetByteCount
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetByteCount
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetByteCount
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetByteCount
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetBytes
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetBytes
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetBytes
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetBytes
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetBytes
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetCharCount
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetCharCount
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetChars
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetChars
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetChars
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetPreamble
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetString
SysUtils.TEncoding -> GetString
SysUtils.TMBCSEncoding -> GetPreamble
SysUtils.TUTF8Encoding -> GetPreamble
SysUtils.TUnicodeEncoding -> GetPreamble
SysUtils.TBigEndianUnicodeEncoding -> GetPreamble
Rtti.TRttiMethod -> Invoke
Rtti.TRttiMethod -> Invoke
Rtti.TRttiMethod -> Invoke
Generics.Collections.TList<Rtti.TMethodImplementation.TParamLoc> -> AddRange
Generics.Collections.TList<Rtti.TMethodImplementation.TParamLoc> -> AddRange
Generics.Collections.TList<Rtti.TMethodImplementation.TParamLoc> -> AddRange
Generics.Collections.TList<Rtti.TMethodImplementation.TParamLoc> -> InsertRange
Generics.Collections.TList<Rtti.TMethodImplementation.TParamLoc> -> InsertRange
Generics.Collections.TList<Rtti.TMethodImplementation.TParamLoc> -> InsertRange
Generics.Collections.TArray -> Sort
Generics.Collections.TArray -> Sort
Generics.Collections.TArray -> Sort
Generics.Collections.TArray -> BinarySearch
Generics.Collections.TArray -> BinarySearch
Generics.Collections.TArray -> BinarySearch
```

i wrote this small app to check this behavior

```
program ProjectTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils;

Function IsFunction(QualifiedName,MethodName:string):Boolean;
Var
  ctx     : TRttiContext;
  lType   : TRttiType;
  lMethod : TRttiMethod;
Begin
    result:=false;
    ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
    lType:=ctx.FindType(QualifiedName);
    if Assigned(lType) then
    begin
       lMethod:=lType.GetMethod(MethodName);
       try
         if Assigned(lMethod) then
           Result:=(lMethod.ReturnType<>nil);
       except on e : exception do
           Writeln(Format('%s %s -> %s',[e.Message,QualifiedName,MethodName]));
       end;
    end;
End;


var
  ctx     : TRttiContext;
  lType   : TRttiType;
  lMethod : TRttiMethod;
begin
  try
    ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
    for lType in  ctx.GetTypes do
       for lMethod in lType.GetDeclaredMethods do
         IsFunction(lType.QualifiedName,lMethod.Name);
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

which is the correct way to determine if an `TRttiMethod` is a function?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the  @Barry suggestions,  i rewrote the function to avoid the exception, however this does not solve the problem of how to determine if a `TRttiMethod` is a function or not due to current limitations of the RTTI.

```
function IsFunction(lType : TRttiType;MethodName:string):Boolean;
Var
  ctx     : TRttiContext;
  lMethod : TRttiMethod;
Begin
    result:=false;
    if Assigned(lType) then
    begin
       lMethod:=lType.GetMethod(MethodName);
         if Assigned(lMethod) then
           if lMethod.HasExtendedInfo then
            Result:= (lMethod.MethodKind in [mkFunction,mkClassFunction]) //you can be 100 % sure, wich this is a function or not
           else // sorry but the RTTI does not provide this information when the TRttiMethod contains parameters or an resultype that are not supported by the RTTI
             Result:=False;
    end;
End;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check `TRttiMethod.HasExtendedInfo` to avoid the exception. The class throws an exception for attempts to access properties for which data is only available if `HasExtendedInfo` returns `True`.

You could consider checking the `MethodKind` property to see if it's `mkFunction` or `mkClassFunction`, etc. as needed. `MethodKind` returns `mkProcedure` if `HasExtendedInfo` is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Your IsFunction function should work fine in most cases.  But some functions don't have RTTI generated for them, because their parameters include types that don't have RTTI available, such as `TBytes` or `array of const`.  But for most functions, your function will work.  [I just hope that the omissions get filled in by the next version.](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/194/rtti-errors-and-omissions-in-delphi-xe)

Comment: this is not an answer. this is a comment.